# What is the meaning of left shift operator for dependsOn in Gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I am looking at the following Gradle code:

```
task createSchema

task loadTestData {
    dependsOn << createSchema
}
```

**What does the left shift operator really do?**
Is it adding a new item in the `dependsOn` collection field in the `loadTestData` task?

Comment: Q: _"Is it adding a new item in the dependsOn collection field in the loadTestData task?"_ A: Yes, it's adding it to the `Set` of [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:dependsOn)

Comment: Please add you post as an answer so I can vote. Follow up question - Where (in which object) is the dependsOn Set defined?

Comment: It's in the link I posted (tasks at the end is a link) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) object, there is [a `dependsOn` property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:dependsOn) that is a `Set` of dependencies.

The left shift adds the task to this set.